# AndroidのNotification通知をロック画面ではプライベートな通知を表示させたい

Tags: android, notification

ロック画面でのNotificationをプライベートなものにしたいです。
Android12を使用しています。

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, getString(R.string.channelname),NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
channel.setDescription(getString(R.string.channeldescription));
channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);・・・（１）
NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
```

（１）前後でchannel.getLockscreenVisibility()を実施したところ、
設定前は-1000、設定後は0に値が変わっていました。

ただし、設定のアプリ情報から通知->ロック画面を確認すると「通知内容をすべて表示」になっており、
「プライベートな通知内容を表示」にはなっていません。

実際、以下で通知を発行しても、ロック画面でも通常の表示がされます（プライベート表示ではない）
//プライベートで表示するもの（ロック画面表示）

```
Notification notificationA = new NotificationCompat.Builder(tihs, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
    .setContentTitle("プライベート！")
    .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
    .build();
//通常で表示するもの
Notification notificationB = new NotificationCompat.Builder(tihs, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
    .setContentTitle("通常！")
    .setContentText("通常メッセージ！")
    .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
    .setPublicVersion(notificationA)
    .build();
//通知
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
otificationManager.notify(1, notificationB);
```

なにか処理がおかしいでしょうか？（使い方があやまっていますでしょうか？）
ちなみに
設定のアプリ情報から通知->ロック画面->「プライベートな通知内容を表示」に変更すると期待した動きになりました。